# How to run an EXE application from C++ on windows CE

Tags: c++, windows-ce

How can one write a C++ dll function (for windows CE) to call an exe application

e.g the exe path is   \DOC\EXE\WINCE_EXE

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

did you try CreateProcess, same as on desktop windows?

Comment: yes but it doesn't seem working                             LPCWSTR  pathA=L"\\CF\\PosClient\\sim\\CardReader_WinCE.exe";                                                              if (CreateProcess(pathB,NULL , NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo))
 {     ::WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);     
       CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);     
       CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
 }

Comment: using getlast error it says encontered unexcpted error and must be closed.